# Avoid having to rewrite function calls whenever parameters change

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I frequently write more advanced wrapper functions that call primitive functions I wrote earlier in a module.  The point is to re-use code from the primitive function and do something extra but optional.  The pain point is whenever I update the primitive function's parameters, I have to adjust for that in the advanced function.  Is there a way to make this dynamic through the way the advanced function is written (something like below)?  Or is there a better solution in general?

I could just write an all-encompassing general function, but I think it would be a waste of code.

It's usually like the example below but with deeper and deeper nested functions in additional wrappers to add additional optional parameters.

advanced/wrapper function

```
def pb_jam_sandwich(sandwich, pb, jam=None):
    if jam is None:
        pb_sandwich(sandwich, pb)
    else:
        pb_sandwich(sandwich, pb)
        add_jam(jam)
```

I was thinking something like this for the advanced function, if it worked:

```
def pb_jam_sandwich(*args, jam=None):
    if jam is None:
        pb_sandwich(*args)
    else:
        pb_sandwich(*args)
        add_jam(jam)
```

Comment: Have you looked into [decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators)? That is their primary purpose, do the original function, plus something additional, e.g. `@add_jam`

Comment: I've provided an answer with an alternate design, but I'm not sure this question can be answered objectively without more detail about your real code. As it stands, I suspect any answer will be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Decorators came to mind b/c they sound topical here, but I don't know how I would use them in this case.

@chepner I should've been more clear about my use case.  I typically write general functions (with more parameters) in terms of specific functions in order to prevent re-writing code.  The general function might call the specific function 10 times for example.

Comment: @chepner I made a new example in the original question to illustrate the use case.  The advanced/general function calls the specific one and does something extra depending on whether it's needed.  For a better or worse, a lot of my code ends up like this, with more and more specific functions calling the general ones.  I can't think of how to change this without re-writing it as a big general function, with lots of re-used code.

Comment: The duplication is unnecessary; call `pb_sandwich`, *then* check if `add_jam` needs to be called. At that point, you are again confronted with the possibility that you don't need a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I think your design is backwards. More specific functions should be defined in terms of more general ones.

```
# Note: no default values
def pbandjsandwich(pb, sandwich, jam):
    return pb + sandwich + jam

def pbsandwich(pb, sandwich):
    return pbandjsandwich(pb, sandwich, 0)
```

Now you can ask the question of whether or not you need a separate function `pbsandwich` at all, or if a default value for `jam` is sufficient:

```
def pbandjsandwich(pb, sandwich, jam=0):
    return pb + sandwich + jam
```

Avoiding a second function call would be more efficient, at least.